# object is not callable error in pytube when I try to insert a YouTube link

Tags: python, pytube

When I try to use this code (in pytube):

```
import pytube as Youtube
tr = Youtube("https://youtu.be/6MUP0bItFQU")
```

This error appears to me:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Change the first line to `from pytube import Youtube`, like in the example [here](https://pytube.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Yes, just remember the spelling is `from pytube import YouTube`.

Comment: Since the answer seems to meet your needs, consider clicking the checkmark, so people can tell your question no longer requires an(other) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're importing the module `pytube` and calling it `YouTube`, where you really want to `from pytube import YouTube`, which is importing `YouTube` from the `pytube` module.

You get that error because you call `YouTube` with `Youtube("https://youtu.be/6MUP0bItFQU")` - but since `YouTube` is just the renamed `pytube` module at that point, you're calling a module (and not a class constructor or some other function).

So:

```
from pytube import YouTube
tr = YouTube("https://youtu.be/6MUP0bItFQU")
```

The [documentation of PyTube shows the same](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html), and provides some examples of how to continue use.